# How to access the child in xml file?

Tags: javascript, xml

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text, parser, xmlDoc;

text = "<bookstore><book>" +
"<title><name> Everyday Italian </name></title>" +
"<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>" +
"<year>2005</year>" +
"</book></bookstore>";

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes["name"].nodeValue;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code I want to access the child of "title" which is "name" in my case. After running script parent(title) cannot access their child "name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. `childNodes` isn't a hash indexed by tag name. Use
   `getElementsByTagName` instead.
2. `nodeValue` will not return the text of an element. Use `textContent` instead.

Also, your code will just fail if the XML doesn't exactly match the structure you expect. You should consider incorporating some error handling as well.

Comment: Ok. Would you like me to make guesses as to why it doesn't work for you, and try to serve something else on a silver platter?

Comment: I am only acknowledge you dude why you are getting so rude.

Comment: Two reasons: 1. You might want to show some appreciation when people try to help you. You're not entitled to help. 2. If you don't tell me why it doesn't work for you, how should I know what would? It works for me.

Comment: Dude i misunderstand your answer.Thanks you have solved my problem